# MVC4 validation with Bootstrap datePicker

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a datepicker textbox that I need to make a required field.
Model:

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Something")]
    [DatePicker] //custom tag builder I wrote to make this a datepicker
    public string DateOfSomething { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @Html.ControlGroupFor(x => x.DateOfSomething) //has the custom tag I built to handle datepicker
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateOfSomething)
```

jquery:

```
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        if ($('#DateOfSomething') == "" || $('#DateOfSomething') == null) {
            $("#ValidationSummary").append("<div>Required</div>");
            $("#ValidationSummary").show();
        }
    });
```

in _layout

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js")"></script>
```

ControlGroupFor extension:

```
     public static MvcHtmlString ControlGroupFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var controlGroupWrapper = BuildTagWith("div", "control-group");
        controlGroupWrapper.InnerHtml += htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "control-label" } }).ToHtmlString();
        var controlDiv2 = BuildTagWith("div", "controls");

        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var inputTag = "";

        var valAttributes = htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(propertyName, metadata);

        if (metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("DatePicker"))
        {
            CreateDatePicker(htmlHelper, expression, propertyName, controlDiv2, controlGroupWrapper);
            controlGroupWrapper.InnerHtml += htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, null, valAttributes);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(controlGroupWrapper.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
        if (metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("DropDownListPropertyName"))
        {
            var propertyNameForOptions = metadata.AdditionalValues["DropDownListPropertyName"] as string;
            var options = GetPropValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, propertyNameForOptions) as Dictionary<string, string>;
            var selectedItem = GetPropValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, propertyName) as string;
            inputTag += BuildSelectList(options, propertyName, selectedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            var value = GetPropValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, propertyName);
            inputTag += htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression).ToHtmlString();
        }
        controlDiv2.InnerHtml += inputTag + htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, null, valAttributes);

        controlGroupWrapper.InnerHtml += controlDiv2.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(controlGroupWrapper.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

I post to the form despite my code attempting to stop it. Any Ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason your `DateOfSomething` property is a `string` instead of a `DateTime`?

Comment: not really, considering MVC converts everything to a string on the view I just do my conversions back to datetime later

Comment: Strongly typing your Model offers many advantages though and namely in this circumstance it will give you tighter validation.  Sure the values are "strings" in the view but when they are posted back MVC Model Binding will automatically validate and convert them to their target types which is a huge plus.

Comment: What does the `ControlGroupFor` helper do?  Any particular reason you're using that instead of `EditorFor`?

Comment: Posted the code for my custom ControlGroupForCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your `click` handler.  That javascript should be unnecessary since it should be handled by the jQuery validation and `Required` attribute.  The jQuery validation also handles cancelling the submit if one or more of the fields is invalid.

Comment: That does make more sense but the form is still submitted

Comment: I am not bundling anything as of yet but I was trying to use the built in MVC validation but was having no luck. In my edit I have all of the requisite files to get my validation

Comment: Done and same issue now I only have: [DatePicker]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Something")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string DateOfSomething { get; set; }

Comment: Still no luck it appears to be a problem with using the datepicker

Comment: Can you show the definition for your `DatePicker` attribute?  What is it doing and/or how is it used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just EditerFor and JQUery Datapicker.

More on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

Comment: That is true but I am doing all of my control's the same way (drop down lists, textboxes, textareas etc...) and I want to keep consistency throughout my app